# I want to find if one string to anagram of other string or not.My code is not giving a proper output.I don't know what is error in my logic

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
    int a=strlen(str1);
    int b=strlen(str2);
    if(a!=b){printf("NO");return 0;}
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        int k=0;
        for(int j=0;j<a;j++){
            if(str2[i]==str1[j]){k++;
           str1[j]='0';}
        }
        if(k==0){printf("NO");return 0;}
    }
    printf("YES");
}
```

In the above code,if I didn't use `str1[j]='0';`the code is working fine for some inputs .I used this line becoz I want to know if the string is already visited or not. I am sure that the mistake is in this line .But I don't what is  error in this logic.Why shouldn't  I use this line

Comment: It would help to know what the "logic" behind this badly-formatted code is.

Comment: What if the original strings contain `0`s?

Comment: Start simple.  Go through the logic by hand with the strings "aa" "ab"

Comment: A much nicer way to do it is count the occurrence of every symbol A-Z, in each word and then check to see if they have the same components. Also allow for lowercase letters. The code as written would say that Arc and Car are not anagrams.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to check if one string is an anagram of another. I can give three examples:

1. Sort both strings and check if they are equal
2. Count letters in both strings and check if counts of every letter match (it is the easiest and fastest way)
3. For every letter in the first string, try to find a matching letter in the second string. I guess that it's what you were trying to do.

I modified your code to do what I think you were trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    /* I do not recommend declaring arrays inside functions, but it's not
       important right now */
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
    /* Renamed a and b to more meaningful names. And strlen returns size_t, not int */
    size_t str1_len = strlen(str1), str2_len = strlen(str2);
    if (str1_len != str2_len) {
        printf("NO");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; /* Usually, when the program fails, it should not return 0 */
    }
    size_t k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str2_len; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < str1_len; j++) {
            if ((str2[i] != '\0') && (str2[i] == str1[j])) {
                k++;
                /* We mark both letters as matched by substituting them with NULL ('\0').
                   It will not work, if we have '\0' in our alphabet */
                str1[j] = '\0';
                str2[i] = '\0';
            }
        }   
    }
    /* We check, if every letter was matched */
    if (k != str1_len) {
        printf("NO");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("YES");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```